# spaCy sentence separation with dictionary source from OpenAI Whisper / WhisperX?

Tags: nlp, spacy, openai-whisper

WhisperX is a whisper extension that does a really excellent job of text to speech with per-word timestamps.

I'd like to use spaCy to split up the text strings into sensible clauses but maintain a connection to the source dictionary so the result can inform subtitles and other video editing tools.

Is there a pathway to do this in spaCy? Most of the examples I see expect a text string of input.

My source dictionaries from WhisperX will be many multiples of this type of thing:

`"word-level": [ {"text": "So", "start": 27.80031007751938, "end": 27.940671834625324}, { "text": "we've", "start": 27.98077519379845, "end": 28.201343669250647, }, {"text": "got", "start": 28.301602067183463, "end": 28.502118863049095}, { "text": "enough", "start": 28.58232558139535, "end": 28.842997416020673, }, { "text": "books.", "start": 28.983359173126615, "end": 29.223979328165374, }, {"text": "We", "start": 29.2640826873385, "end": 29.364341085271317}, { "text": "hopefully", "start": 29.384392764857882, "end": 29.765374677002583, }, { "text": "enough", "start": 29.885684754521964, "end": 30.18645994832041, }, {"text": "to", "start": 30.607545219638244, "end": 30.72785529715762}, {"text": "be", "start": 30.767958656330748, "end": 30.868217054263564}, {"text": "able", "start": 30.96847545219638, "end": 31.128888888888888}, {"text": "to", "start": 31.168992248062015, "end": 31.26925064599483}, { "text": "share", "start": 31.349457364341085, "end": 31.590077519379843, }, {"text": "some", "start": 31.670284237726097, "end": 31.81064599483204}, {"text": "of", "start": 31.850749354005167, "end": 31.890852713178294}, { "text": "these", "start": 31.93095607235142, "end": 32.071317829457364, }, {"text": "books", "start": 32.15152454780362, "end": 32.41219638242894}, {"text": "with", "start": 32.51245478036176, "end": 32.692919896640824}, {"text": "the", "start": 32.71297157622739, "end": 32.79317829457364}, { "text": "children", "start": 32.833281653746766, "end": 33.194211886304906, }, {"text": "our", "start": 33.254366925064595, "end": 33.37467700258398}, { "text": "community", "start": 33.43483204134367, "end": 33.73560723514212, }, {"text": "at", "start": 33.81581395348837, "end": 33.89602067183462}, {"text": "our", "start": 33.956175710594316, "end": 34.13664082687338}, { "text": "annual", "start": 34.216847545219636, "end": 34.4574677002584, }, { "text": "Christmas", "start": 34.49757105943152, "end": 34.75824289405685, }, {"text": "on", "start": 34.79834625322997, "end": 34.838449612403096}, {"text": "the", "start": 34.87855297157623, "end": 34.938708010335915}, { "text": "Boulevard", "start": 34.95875968992248, "end": 35.25953488372093, }, {"text": "event", "start": 35.27958656330749, "end": 35.37984496124031}, ]`

I've played around with keying in and out of the dictionary, but this feels like a problem that already has a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can create docs from external tokenization like this:

```py
import spacy
from spacy.tokens import Doc
nlp = spacy.blank("en")
doc = Doc(nlp.vocab, words=[entry["text"] for entry in entries])
```

If you need to, you can add additional metadata to the tokens for alignment:

```py
from spacy.tokens import Token
Token.set_extension("my_metadata", default=None)
for i, entry in enumerate(entries):
    doc[i]._.my_metadata = entry["some_index"]
```

If you're using this input for training, you might want to add this flag to the doc, so that the pipeline components know that the spaces between the tokens in the default `doc.text` aren't significant:

```py
doc.has_unknown_spaces = True
```

`We've` and `"books."` are not tokenized the same way by default for the English pipelines, so provided pipelines like `en_core_web_sm` won't do a particularly great job of analyzing this input, especially around sentence boundaries and tokens like `"books."` where it would expect the tokens `["books", "."]`.